# How to avoid remote validation for particular page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have defined Email Property in my MVC class and assigned the validation using data Annotation. I am using this property on two pages namely in user registration and forgot password. My Property is defined below

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid email address")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}" +
                     @"\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\" +
                     @".)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$",
                     ErrorMessage = "Email is not valid")]
    [Remote("IsAlreadySigned", "Account", AdditionalFields = "ID", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Email id already exists")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

My Problem is i want to use all those validation in user registration but i don't want to use Remote validation in forgot password page. Is there any method  where we can use same property and avoid only remote validation for forgot password?

**Note : I don't want to use different property/model only for forgot password**

Comment: Use `HiddenFieldFor` instead of `EditorFor` and set corresponding email value from Database in the View. Also you can change ValidationMethod with some condition whether it is for New User or Change Password

Comment: Other option is you can use Annotation `[NotMapped]` and create a proxy property for Email. This will not affect the database in case you are using Entity Framework